# Maui - FilePicker - Return TextFile FullPath Asynchronously

Tags: maui

The goal is to have a Maui class library that will have a function that return a full path to read a text file in my Maui application.

Can you help me to fix the following code?

The error is when I try to return the FullPath as string

```
var FileFullPath = await result.FullPath.ToString();
```

Here the error description
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error CS1061

'string' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    MPCFilePickerMauiLibrary (net7.0), MPCFilePickerMauiLibrary (net7.0-android), MPCFilePickerMauiLibrary (net7.0-ios), MPCFilePickerMauiLibrary (net7.0-maccatalyst)  D:\repos\MPC-MassPropertiesCalculator\MPCFilePickerMauiLibrary\PickTxtFile.cs   35  Active

Here is the Maui class library that have created.

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Storage;

namespace MPCFilePickerMauiLibrary;

//Ref https://youtu.be/C6LV_xMGdKc - Intro To Class Libraries in C#
public class PickTxtFile
{
    
    public static async Task<string> GetFilePathAsync()

    {
        //For custom file types
        
        var customFileType = new FilePickerFileType(
                new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                    { DevicePlatform.iOS, new[] { "public.text" } }, // UTType values
                    { DevicePlatform.Android, new[] { "text/plain" } }, // MIME type
                    { DevicePlatform.WinUI, new[] { ".Txt" } }, // file extension
                    { DevicePlatform.Tizen, new[] { "*/*" } },
                    { DevicePlatform.macOS, new[] { "Txt" } }, // UTType values
                });


        var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync(new PickOptions
        {
            PickerTitle = "Pick MPC Demo file Please",
            FileTypes = customFileType
        });

        if (result == null)
            return "";


        var FileFullPath = await result.FullPath.ToString();
        return FileFullPath;
        

    }
```

Here is the code where I'm using the function

```
using MPCFilePickerMauiLibrary;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace MPC_MassPropertiesCalculator_MAUIapp.Views;

public partial class MPCFileDemo : ContentPage
{
    public MPCFileDemo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MenuFlyoutItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String filePath = PickTxtFile.GetFilePathAsync();

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            //TODO Read file
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: We can't help you fix it because you haven't told us what's wrong with it.  Do you get an error or exception?  What specific problem are you having or where are you stuck?

Comment: See the update request which include error location and the error description.

Comment: that is not an `async` method, so you can't `await` it

Comment: I'm in learning process. According to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-picker?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=ios)

Comment: nothing in that link says that you should use `await` when calling `FullPath`.  Just remove the `await` keyword from that line

Comment: Agree. Did remove it and that solve the Class library file but now I have the following error in this line 'String filePath = PickTxtFile.GetFilePathAsync();'                           Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>' to 'string' MPC-MassPropertiesCalculator-MAUIapp (net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0) D:\repos\MPC-MassPropertiesCalculator\MPC-MassPropertiesCalculator-MAUIapp\Views\MPCFileDemo.xaml.cs 16 Active

Comment: `GetFilePathAsync` is an **async** method, so you need to use `await` when calling it.  Please read the docs on async/await - this is a basic feature of C# you need to understand

Comment: Thanks problem solved. Here the [async/await ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/). Questions, should I answer my question with the updated code and refer to our discussions.

Comment: Yes, now that you have solved it, add Your Answer below, showing the exact code that works. With mention of commenter(s) that helped.

Answer (score 1):

With [Jason's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338/jason) comments, here is the solution.

**Maui class library**

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Storage;

namespace MPCFilePickerMauiLibrary;

//Ref https://youtu.be/C6LV_xMGdKc - Intro To Class Libraries in C#
public class PickTxtFile
{
    
    public static async Task<string> GetFilePathAsync()

    {
        //For custom file types       
        var customFileType = new FilePickerFileType(
                new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
                {
                    { DevicePlatform.iOS, new[] { "public.text" } }, // UTType values
                    { DevicePlatform.Android, new[] { "text/plain" } }, // MIME type
                    { DevicePlatform.WinUI, new[] { ".Txt" } }, // file extension
                    { DevicePlatform.Tizen, new[] { "*/*" } },
                    { DevicePlatform.macOS, new[] { "Txt" } }, // UTType values
                });

        var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync(new PickOptions
        {
            PickerTitle = "Pick MPC Demo file Please",
            FileTypes = customFileType
        });

        if (result == null)
            return "";

        var FileFullPath = result.FullPath.ToString();
        return FileFullPath;
        
    }
    
}
```

**Code in the application**

```
using MPCFilePickerMauiLibrary;
    
namespace MPC_MassPropertiesCalculator_MAUIapp.Views;

public partial class MPCFileDemo : ContentPage
{
    public MPCFileDemo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void MenuFlyoutItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string? filePath = await PickTxtFile.GetFilePathAsync();

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            await DisplayAlert("File Path", $"File Path is: {filePath}", "OK");
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("File Path", "Usre did not select a file", "OK");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output result image.**

[image]